# How to generate unique alphanumeric string for unlimited time which is not exist in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to generate unique alphanumeric string by checking mysql database. The string can be A-Z and 0-9 combination. I have try floor() and rand() function but there is a possibility to repeat same string if vast number of user try once.

Comment: Hint:  `UUID()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid).

Comment: Please go read How to Ask, and how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you generate random number/string it's **always** possible to get the same string. However, if you generate 16-char (or more) length string it's unlikely that you will ever get the same string.

You can generate random string and then check if it exist in database. In that very rare situation you can generate new random string in while loop until you find one that is free. As I wrote before, even 16 characters length text with [A-Z0-9] is almost impossible to repeat. It's 36^16 possible combinations.

You can also pregenerate let's say 1000 strings, sort them by random order and put into database. After that you simply choose first unsued string from database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `uniqid()` function, which is generate string current time based. If you want upper case letters use like this:

```
strtoupper(uniqid());
```